# Backticks creates jQuery error in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, mobile-browser, backticks

I have a text which was retrieved from my database with `PHP` and has characters like `"` `'` and also has line breaks. Now I passed it to a `jQuery` string using the backticks like this

```
var str = `<?php echo $text; ?>`;
```

And it works fine with desktop browsers but when I try it with mobile browsers though I can't see the console.log in mobile browsers but I believe I am getting some errors because my jQuery code refuse to function, but when I comment out the above line it works fine. Please anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: That's a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which is a newer kind of string literal. They are new to ES6, which means they aren't supported in some browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're relying on a fairly new feature of JavaScript (officially introduced in June 2015 as part of ES2015, aka "ES6"): [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It's not surprising you're running into browsers with older JavaScript engines that don't support template literals.

It would also fail if the output happened to *contain* backticks.

The correct thing to do here is *properly escape* the string content. PHP's `json_encode` will happily take a string and output a JavaScript-compatible, escaped version for you:

```
var str = <?php echo json_encode($text); ?>;
```

If `$text` contains a string, for instance:

```
Bob: Hi, my name is Bob, but people call me "Bobby;" it's a nickname.
Wilma: Hi Bobby!
```

what would arrive at the browser would be:

```
var str = "Bob: Hi, my name is Bob, but people call me \"Bobby;\" it's a nickname.\nWilma: Hi Bobby!";
```

Comment: That's a great tip!

Comment: Thanks so much @Crowder